# Completed 401 Unauthorized in 119ms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, single-sign-on, saml

I am using `devise_saml_authenticatable` gem in my rails application to integrate it with external SSO, I have configured my application but I am getting `Completed 401 Unauthorized in 119ms` from devise/saml_sessions controller.

My config/initializers/devise.rb

```
config.saml_create_user = true
config.saml_update_user = true
config.saml_default_user_key = :email
config.saml_session_index_key = :session_index
config.saml_use_subject = true
config.idp_settings_adapter = CidpSettingsAdapter
```

IDP Settings Adapter

```
class CidpSettingsAdapter
  def self.settings(idp_entity_id)
        {
        issuer: 'https://devidentity.greenfence.com/users/saml/metadata',
        assertion_consumer_service_url: 'https://devidentity.greenfence.com/saml/consume',
        assertion_consumer_service_binding: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',
        #assertion_consumer_logout_service_url: 'https://devidentity.greenfence.com/users/saml/sign_out',
        idp_entity_id: 'https://cargill.identitynow.com',
        authn_context: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport',
        name_identifier_format: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified',
        idp_sso_target_url: 'https://prd02-useast1-sso.identitynow.com/sso/SSOPOST/metaAlias/cargill/idp',
        idp_slo_target_url: 'https://prd02-useast1-sso.identitynow.com/sso/IDPSloPOST/metaAlias/cargill/idp',
        security: {
          authn_requests_signed: false,
          logout_requests_signed: false,
          logout_responses_signed: false,
          metadata_signed: false,
          digest_method: XMLSecurity::Document::SHA1,
          signature_method: XMLSecurity::Document::RSA_SHA1
        },
        idp_cert:  <<-CERT.chomp
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
        CERT
      }
  end
end
```

My config/routes.rb

```
  devise_scope :user do
    get 'users/sign_out', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy'
    get 'users/submit_verification_code', to: 'aws_cognito#submit_verification_code'
    get 'users/request_verification_code', to: 'aws_cognito#request_verification_code'

    scope 'users', controller: 'saml_sessions' do
      get :new, path: 'saml/sign_in', as: :new_user_saml_session
      post :create, path: 'saml/auth', as: :user_saml_session
      get :destroy, path: 'saml/sign_out', as: :destroy_user_saml_session
      get :metadata, path: 'saml/metadata', as: :metadata_user_saml_session
      match :idp_sign_out, path: 'saml/idp_sign_out', via: [:get, :post]
      get :sso_dashboard
    end
    post '/saml/consume' => 'saml_sessions#create'
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed by providing correct `issuer` name in `CidpSettingsAdapter`.